# Error: cannot find name "Stripe" in my Next JS app

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I'm making an app in next js that requires payments with stripe. When I define stripe like so, It says cannot find name 'Stripe'.

```
export const stripe:any = Stripe('stripe public key')
```

I know why this error comes up, because I am importing the stripe js code in my app.jsx file like so.

```
<script src='https://www.js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>
```

Despite the error the stripe checkout works just fine, but I can't deploy my code by running npm run build with the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are including stripe.js in frontend, and trying to use Stripe in backend (looking at "secret key" and how you are initializing Stripe object). I am not familiar with NextJS, but possibly they are completely different things

Comment: Sorry should've said publishable key but this code is on the front end and works fine until I try and run build

Comment: How are you importing and using the `stripe` module? Can you show us the full error/error stack?